# Why use 'instance_eval' instead of creating a method?

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

Here's a code sample:

```
class Book
  def initialize
    @v = "abc"
  end
end

b = Book.new
b.instance_eval do
  def book_name
  end
end
```

Why do we use `instance_eval` to create a method (`book_name`) instead of adding `book_name` method inside class `Book`? The method (`book_name`) created using `instance_eval` will be accessible only by object `b` in the case above. Is there any particular use case?

Comment: Please edit to change `Class Book` to `class Book`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instance_eval` is very useful when some kind of metaprogramming is needed, like when defining methods during instance initialization or inside frameworks.

Why use it? It's usually faster than calling `define_method` in these cases and, if adding a bunch of methods at the same time, invalidates the method cache just once.

On your specific example the method is being created only on the `b` instance, making it what is called a `singleton method`, meaning it only exists for this particular instance. The author could have used `eval` but since it evaluate code on a more global scope, it's considered unsafe.

Edit:

The same effect would be produced if you defined the method using `b` as the receiver

```
def b.book_name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The author of this codes wanted `book_name` to be a method which belongs only to `b`. If he had created inside the class definition, it would belong to every object of class `Book`.

Comment: Is that the only reason we use instance_eval

Comment: This is already mentioned in question. "The method(book_name) created using instance_eval will be accessible only by object b in above case"

Comment: @JagdeepSingh : I see that the question has been edited in the meantime.

Comment: @rohankharvi : No, there are several other uses for `instance_eval`, for example to access a instance variable of an object from the outside. Also, adding methods to an object can also be achieved in different ways.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh in this case, `define_singleton_method` would be a more idiomatic way to achieve the same result

Comment: @Max: Since there is nothing dynamic about the method, neither the name nor the body, I would argue that the *only* idiomatic way would be `def`.